# Link errors with curlpp

Tags: c++, curl, linker, curlpp

I wrote a c++ program and try to use curlpp to access a http server securely over `SSL`. The problem is, that I can't link the program.

Operating system: **Ubuntu 15.10**

Errors:

> /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
>   CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>       Wird gelinkt prtg_probe (c++)
>       CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/probe.cpp.o: In function curlpp::internal::OptionContainer, std::allocator >,
>   std::allocator, std::allocator > > >
>
> > ::OptionContainer(std::__cxx11::list, std::allocator >,
> >     std::allocator, std::allocator > > > const&)':
> >         /usr/include/curlpp/internal/OptionContainer.inl:38: undefined reference to
> >     curlpp::internal::SList::SList(std::__cxx11::list, std::allocator >,
> >     std::allocator, std::allocator > > > const&)'
> >         CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/probe.cpp.o: In function curlpp::internal::OptionContainer, std::allocator >,
> >     std::allocator, std::allocator > > >
> >     ::setValue(std::__cxx11::list, std::allocator >,
> >     std::allocator, std::allocator > > > const&)':
> >         /usr/include/curlpp/internal/OptionContainer.inl:52: undefined reference to
> >     `curlpp::internal::SList::operator=(std::__cxx11::list, std::allocator >,
> >     std::allocator, std::allocator > > > const&)'
> >         ....

This is the code that produces the errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>

....

class myclass
{

....

try
{
    curlpp::Cleanup cleaner;
    curlpp::Easy request;
    ostringstream os;

    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(&url_announce[0]));
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::SslEngineDefault());
    list<string> header;
    header.push_back("Content-Type: text/*");
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpHeader(header));
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(data_announce));
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFieldSize((long)data_announce.length()));
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(&os));
    request.perform();
    request_announce = os.str();
}
catch (curlpp::LogicError & e)
{
    syslog(LOG_DAEMON, "Error accessing PRTG server: %s", e.what());
}
catch (curlpp::RuntimeError & e)
{
    syslog(LOG_DAEMON, "Error accessing PRTG server: %s", e.what());
}
```

Every line with `curlpp::options::...` produces one error at link time. I've looked around and searched Google for hours now, but all I found was to link libcurl together with libcurl. I do that, but still get this errors.

Here is the complete link line:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -g    CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/sensors.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/mini_probe.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/probe.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/helper.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/config.cpp.o CMakeFiles/prtg_probe.dir/main.cpp.o
-o prtg_probe -rdynamic -lm -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -lcurlpp -lcurl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -ljsoncpp -luuid
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing? Do I have to add one more library and if yes which one?

---

I've tried to compile the [example00.cpp](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/blob/master/examples/example00.cpp) with the following command:

```
g++ -o example00 example00.cpp -lm -lcurl -lcurlpp
```

and the result:

```
/tmp/cc3pcvDc.o: In Funktion `curlpp::OptionTrait<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, (CURLoption)10002>::updateHandleToMe(curlpp::internal::CurlHandle*) const':
example00.cpp: (.text._ZNK6curlpp11OptionTraitINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEL10CURLoption10002EE16updateHandleToMeEPNS_8internal10CurlHandleE[_ZNK6curlpp11OptionTraitINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEL10CURLoption10002EE16updateHandleToMeEPNS_8internal10CurlHandleE]+0x68):
Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/cc3pcvDc.o: In Funktion `curlpp::Option<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::getValue() const':
example00.cpp: (.text._ZNK6curlpp6OptionINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8getValueEv[_ZNK6curlpp6OptionINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8getValueEv]+0x68):
Nicht definierter Verweis auf `curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This looks like the same problem to me.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example with your problem. Throw out all lines not related to a single curlpp::options line, remove all additional libraries. If the minimal set works, add more lines and libraries until it breaks.

Comment: As you can see above, I get the same errors when I try to compile one of the examples included in cURLpp.

Comment: Have you tried with inverse ordering? `-lcurlpp -lcurl -lm`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that linkage of `ccurlcpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption`
is partially defective in the `lipcurlcpp.so` binary.

The linker's complaint with:

```
g++ -o example00 example00.cpp -lm -lcurl -lcurlpp
```

is:

```
undefined reference to `curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

But if I demangle the constructor signatures in `libcurlpp.so`:

```
nm -D -C libcurlpp.so | grep UnsetOption::UnsetOption
```

I see:

```
0000000000021776 T curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(char const*)
000000000002173e T curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::string const&)
```

The `std::string` hasn't been properly de-typedefed for some reason. If
I get the source file in which this constructor is defined from the
`curlpp 0.7.3` source package, `Exception.cpp`, compile it:

```
curlpp-0.7.3/src/curlpp$ g++ -I../../include -I. -c Exception.cpp
```

and then demangle the constructor signatures from the object file:

```
nm -C Exception.o | grep UnsetOption::UnsetOption
```

I get:

```
00000000000003f4 T curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(char const*)
00000000000003c2 T curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

So:

```
curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

is the signature the compiler is telling the linker to look for, but that is
not the signature in the library. The short explanation of the error is: the library is broken.

However, we see that no such inconsistency affects the other overload of the constructor:

```
curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(char const*)
```

nor could it, since the `char const *` is a builtin type.

This enables a hack fix. The file in which the undefined-reference call is
compiled is (as installed)  `/usr/include/curlpp/Option.inl`, at the line:

```
throw UnsetOption(std::string("You are trying to set an unset option to a handle"));
```

Edit this file, as root, and you see that it (inconsistently) contains two instances
of:

```
throw UnsetOption(std::string("blah blah"));
```

and one instance of:

```
throw UnsetOption("blah blah");
```

Change the occurrences of `UnsetOption(std::string("blah blah"))` to `UnsetOption("blah blah")`.
Then only the good constructor is called in this file and `example00`, at least, will
compile and link.

If you dislike the hack, or find that the problem re-surfaces elsewhere, then you
may download the ubuntu source package [`curlpp_0.7.3.orig.tar.gz`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curlpp/0.7.3-6)
and build and install it yourself. That is the right remedy.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation. I got the source and compiled the library. Now I was able to link the examples and they work.

Comment: @A.T. You're welcome. If the answer solves your problem you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)
so it no longer appears to be unanswered on SO. You get some reputation points for this, and so do I.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to compile your project using old ABI:
g++ -o example00 example00.cpp -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -lm -lcurl -lcurlpp

Comment: Simple method! Great!

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
apt-get install libcurlpp-dev
```

Cmake:

```
...
add_executable(HTTPPostTest HTTPPostTest.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(HTTPPostTest -lcurl -lcurlpp stdc++fs )
...
```

HTTPPostTest.cpp:

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        curlpp::Cleanup cleaner;
        curlpp::Easy request;
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url("https://postman-echo.com/post"));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Verbose(true));
        std::list<std::string> header;
        header.push_back("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpHeader(header));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields("abcd"));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFieldSize(5));
        request.perform();
    } catch ( curlpp::LogicError & e ) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch ( curlpp::RuntimeError & e ) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```